# Putting each element of line to an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a txt file, and I need to put every element of line (string, space) to an array.

example:

1 line "Hey, 1 day \n"

2 /// etc

output for first line:  ["H" "e" "y" "," " " "1" "d" "a" "y"]

Which way for do this is the most optimal? Using split and string or maybe operating on char type?

Comment: can't you just use `string.toCharArray`

Comment: You mean put the whole line into a string and then use this method?

Comment: Is the problem reading the file? Or getting the characters of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just call [`String#toCharArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) on the string?

Readers will truncate newlines if you use `nextLine` anyway.

Something like:

```
try(BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("topSecretDocs.txt"))) {
    for(String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
        char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
        System.out.println("Split line to " + Arrays.toString(chars));
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    dealWithException();
}
```

**Edit:** Note that you may want to loop through the string using [`String#charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) instead, because it is unnecessary to copy the character array, especially for very large strings.

**Edit 2:** Here's a very bad benchmark.

```
static long time(Runnable r) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    r.run();
    return System.nanoTime() - start;
}

static int cs = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] bigString = new char[100000];
    Arrays.fill(bigString, 0, bigString.length / 4, 'A');
    Arrays.fill(bigString, bigString.length / 4, bigString.length / 2, 'B');
    Arrays.fill(bigString, bigString.length / 2, bigString.length * 3 / 4, 'C');
    Arrays.fill(bigString, bigString.length * 3 / 4, bigString.length, 'D');
    String s = new String(bigString);
    float avgCopy = 0, avgLoop = 0;
    final int times = 100000;
    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        avgLoop += time(() -> {
            cs = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
                cs += s.charAt(j) == 'C' ? 1 : 0;
        });
    } avgLoop /= times;
    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        avgCopy += time(() -> {
            char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
            cs = 0;
            for(char c : chars)
                cs += c == 'C' ? 1 : 0;
        });
    } avgCopy /= times;
    System.out.println("copy: " + avgCopy + " ns");
    System.out.println("loop: " + avgLoop + " ns");
    System.out.println("There were (obviously) " + cs + " Cs in that string.");
}
```

I get:

```
copy: 70984.336 ns
loop: 40534.63 ns
```

So, around half as fast. Whether or not you'd like to call that a significant difference I'll leave up to you.